# Can you compile a shared library in C++ with debug symbols?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I am new to C/C++. I have been reading up on debugging with gdb, and the examples I have seen are simple, and compile a main.c or main.cpp file and then run the file. My question is if it is possible to compile a library with debug symbols? In the case of a shared library, if I ran the following commands 
`gcc -c -g -fpic test.cpp -I include`
`gcc -shared -o libtest.so test.o`

I would expect the output to be `libtest.so`, but this is a library and not an executable. How would you go about debugging the .cpp files within the library?

Comment: First, compile your library with `-ggdb` then link it to your program and call the library functions and start tracing.

Comment: You need to use `-g` when linking as well as compiling. You should also use `g++` not `gcc` when building and linking c++ code